# How to convert a RGB Mat to HSV and set hue the value with OpenCv in c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb, mat, hsv

I've worked on school project. And now I want to use a HSV Mat and then set the value of hue while maintain the sat and value at 100. Here is my code:

```
Mat imgRGB(Size(8, 8), CV_8U);
Mat imgHSV(Size(8, 8), CV_8U);
cvtColor(imgRGB, imgHSV, CV_RGB2HSV);
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
        imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 180 * i / 8;
        imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 100;
        imgHSV.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 100;
    }
}
Mat resizedHSV;
resize(imgHSV, resizedHSV, Size(640, 640));
imshow("HSV", resizedHSV); 
waitKey(0);
```

Somehow VS2013 always told me that there is a cv::Exception. I found that the problem is on cvtColor() and for loop, but I often saw people use these function. I have no idea why this would fail. Could someone notice me. Thanks!!!

Comment: instead of CV_8U use CV_8UC3 to create 3 channel mat (for both: RGB and HSV mats). To avoid future error: if you import images theyre probably BGR instead of RGB, if thats the case you must use that type un cvtColor.

Comment: Oh!!!CV_8UC3 is work. Thanks~

Comment: As @Micka pointed out, `CV_RGB2HSV` and `CV_BGR2HSV` gives different results. Use `CV_BGR2HSV`. Also note that for 8 channel matrix, the value H is halved, so that the original range [0, 360] fits in [0,255]

Comment: Thanks again. But somehow I found that the mat is still BGR color space. Is there something I missed?